# Парадокс с кодировкой

Tags: php, javascript, кодировка

Здравствуйте, у меня проблемы с кодировкой чата... Он состоит из файла-вставки и самой странички с формой и инклудом.
На главной чата я вставляю код:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_chat').load('chat-include.php').fadeIn('slow');
}, 5000);
</script>
```

И с момощью <div id='load_chat'></div> чат грузится со страницы chat-include.php
Там такой код:

```
<?php
echo "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1251'>";
$letters="messages.dat";
$data=@file($letters);
$data=@array_reverse($data);
$ncol=count($data);
if (file_exists($letters)) {
for ($i=0; $i<$ncol; $i++){
list($login,$message,$time)=split(":::","$data[$i]");
echo "<table width='100%' class='message'>
<tr><td><b>$login</b></td><td width='50'>$time</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'>$message</td></tr></table>";}}
else {echo "<center><font color='white'>Сообщений нет</font></center>";}
?>
```

Проблема в том, что выходит что-то странное... Если убрать в коде выше <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1251'>, то все браузеры отображают чат хорошо, кроме Хрома, а если оставить, то наоборот, у Хрома всё окей, а в остальных какие - то квадратики... Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста;)
[Вот тест чата](http://lifesims.ru/myportfoliosites/thesimstowns/chat.php)

Comment: я бы не об этом думал. с кодировкой все в порядке, в браузере нужно поставить просто кодировку автоматом.

а вотто что он на быстром инете оооооооооочень долго нрузится после отправки сообщения...

Comment: сколько? обновление поставлено на каждые 5 секунд просто и после первой отправки она загружается так) или вы о другом?

Comment: да и не каждый додумается поставить автокодировку...

Answer (score 1):

А по-моему тут дело вот в чём : Через Ajax данные передаются в кодировке utf-8, а ваши страницы в cp1251, совет : переходите на utf-8, должно помочь.

Comment: не помогло

Comment: Если вы про переход, то не всё так просто, посмотрите ответ участника http://hashcode.ru/questions/26057#26084

Comment: сделал с помощью .htaccess

Comment: Там ещё заголовок нужно отправить с помощью функции header(),  к сожалению текст подсказать не могу.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

возможно это вам поможет, вставьте в пхп скрипт
```